# Activation URL not generated properly in confirmation mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have one problem with my site. Recently my site started do not show properly acivation url that is send to confirmation mail. The same script was used long time before without any issue. This is code how is get variable

```
%activation_url_code%
```

and this is code from **register.php** file:

```
if ($settings['register_activation'] == "yes") {
        $mail_id = "registration_activation";
        $activation_code = md5(time() . $username);
        $str2find = array("%site_name%", "%site_url%", "%fullname%", "%username%", "%activation_code%", "%activation_url_code%", "%activation_url%");
        $str2change = array($settings['site_name'], $settings['site_url'], $fullname, $username, $activation_code, $settings['site_url'] . "?view=activation&username=" . $username . "&i=" . $activation_code, $settings['site_url'] . "?view=activation");
        $newdata2 = array("status" => "Un-verified", "verifycode" => $activation_code);
    }
```

and when get confirmation mail content show me like this:

[issue from mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGkcZ.png)

what may cause this issue? i use php 5.5 currently. the same issue persist on all lowere versions too (including 5.6 too)

Comment: You haven't shown the code that exchanges the values or the variable that contains the email.

Comment: It seems somewhere in your code you are finding $str2find and changing it with $str2change , the problem should be there , Please edit your question and put the code